# TypeError: is not a function in [null] getting this error in component while calling method of service in angular2

Tags: angular

I am displaying data in table format from a mock data. Getting error in component while calling getItems method of service even when the service is injected inside the component. Can anyone help me out as I have just started learning angular

app.ts

```
//our root app component
import {Component, OnInit, Provide} from 'angular2/core'
import {ItemController} from './ItemController';
import {ItemControllerService} from './ItemController.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [ItemControllerService] ,


  template: `
    <div>
    <table border=1 ng-controller="ItemController">

      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>Event</th>
      <th>Benefit Name</th>
      <th>Inactive from date</th>


    <tbody *ngFor="#item of items">
        <tr>
            <td>{{item.id}}</td>
            <td>{{item.location}}</td>
            <td>{{item.event}}</td>
            <td>{{item.benefit}}</td>
            <td>{{item.inactivedate}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>


    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class App {
  items: ItemController[];
   constructor(private service: ItemControllerService){}



  getitems(){

    this.service.getItems().then(items=>this.items = items);

  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.getitems();
  }
}
```

Error is at line this.service.getItems().then(items=>this.items = items);
ItemControllerService

```
import {Item} from './ItemController';
import {Injectable,Inject} from 'angular2/core';
import {ITEMS} from './mock-items';
import {ItemController} from './ItemController';



@Injectable()
export class ItemControllerService{


   getItems{
  return Promise.resolve(ITEMS);          
}

}
```

Comment: Hi! Can you post the mock data?

Comment: Is it a copy-paste error or did you just miss the parentheses after the `getItems` method in the `ItemControllerService`? -> `getItems() {...}`.

Comment: oh dear i am feeling embarassed I forgot the parentheses...sorry for all the trouble

Comment: Don't mind. This can happen to anybody. Please have a look at the TypeScript compiler output because this should be marked there as an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot the parentheses after getItems...!!!!

Answer (score 0):

This won't fix your problem, but there is something wrong with your `template`. It should look like this:

```html
<table border=1>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>Event</th>
      <th>Benefit Name</th>
      <th>Inactive from date</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="#item of items">
      <td>{{item.id}}</td>
      <td>{{item.location}}</td>
      <td>{{item.event}}</td>
      <td>{{item.benefit}}</td>
      <td>{{item.inactivedate}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Fixes html and your don't need `ng-controller`

Please also provide code of `ItemController`

Comment: Considering the fact that angular 2 is already in rc5, you should use angular.io's https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#create-and-configure to create your app.